# OCaml - Add a new tuple, containing a list of tuples, to that list

Tags: list, recursion, closures, ocaml, tuples

I'm writing an interactive calculator in OCaml with some simple commands. Users should be able, among other things, to define their own simple functions (mathematical functions), for instance

```
let f(x) = x
let g(x) = 2*f(x)
```

Now, the functions should be handled like in functional languages, that means they should remember their time-of-creation environment. That means, that with a function I have to keep a closure of its environment, which is functions and variables.

I keep currently defined functions in a list of tuples formed like `(functions_present_at_the_time_of_creation, variables_present_at_the_time_of_creation, function_name, function_argument_names, function_formula)`. When I try to add a new function to the list of functions (let's assume, that it's not currently defined and I don't have to overwrite anything), I recurrently iterate to the end of the list of functions and there would like to add a new tuple.

The problem is, assuming my current functions list is of type `(a*b*c*d*e) list` when i try to add a tuple with itself to the end of it, it changes its type to `((a*b*c*d*e) list*f*g*h*i) list`. What can I do to be able to perform such addition of a list to itself, encapsulated in a tuple?

Here's some simple SSCCE I wrote while trying to find a workaround to this issue.

```
let rec add_to_end list list_copy dummy = match list with
| [] -> [(list_copy, dummy)]
| h::t -> h::(add_to_end t list_copy dummy) 

let add list dummy = add_to_end list list dummy
```

This one tries to do it with a copy of the list. The following one is written without using of a copy (both of these examples don't work, of course):

```
let rec add_to_end list dummy = match list with
| [] -> [(list, dummy)]
| h::t -> h::(add_to_end t dummy)
```

The first example doesn't work when trying to use the function add, but when doing it for instance this way (in the interpreter):

```
let l = [];;
let l = add_to_end l l 1;;
let l = add_to_end l l 2;;
let l = add_to_end l l 3;;
```

Then it works fine. I'd appreciate any help, I may think about changing the design also, any proposals are very welcome.

Edit: Here's the output of the above commands:

```
# let l = [];;
val l : 'a list = []
# let l = add_to_end l l 1;;
val l : ('a list * int) list = [([], 1)]
# let l = add_to_end l l 2;;
val l : (('a list * int) list * int) list = [([], 1); ([([], 1)], 2)]
# let l = add_to_end l l 3;;
val l : ((('a list * int) list * int) list * int) list =
[([], 1); ([([], 1)], 2); ([([], 1); ([([], 1)], 2)], 3)]
```

Comment: Are we going to anything here, Jeffrey? Because I think, I should better redesign my program. It seems too complicated now, let alone the `-rectypes`. Although I still don't know how I should emulate closures with my own types. Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell whether you're aware that OCaml lists are immutable. You can't add a value to the end of an existing list. An existing list can never be changed. You can create a new list with a value added to the end. If you do this, I don't see why you would want to add a pair to the end consisting of the list and the new value. I suspect you're thinking about it wrong. Here's a function that takes a list and an integer and adds the integer to the end of the list.

```
# let rec addi i list =
    match list with
    | [] -> [i]
    | h :: t -> h :: addi i t
  ;;
val addi : 'a -> 'a list -> 'a list = <fun>
# let x = [1;2;3];;
val x : int list = [1; 2; 3]
# addi 4 x;;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4]
# x;;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3]
#
```

The function returns a new list with the value added to the end.  The original list isn't changed.

As a side comment, it's much more idiomatic to add values to the *front* of a list. Repeatedly adding to the end of the list is slow--it gives quadratic behavior. If you want the other order, the usual thing to do is add everything to the front and then reverse the list--this is still linear.

**Edit**

Apparently you really want a function that looks something like this:

let f a list = list @ [(list, a)]

This is not realistically possible, the types don't work out right. A list can contain things of only one type. So you can conclude that the type of the list `t` is the same as the type `(t, v) list`, where `v` is the type of a. This is a recursive type, not something you would really want to be working with (IMHO).

You can actually get this type in OCaml using `-rectypes`:

```
$ ocaml -rectypes
        OCaml version 4.00.0

# let f a list = list @ [(list, a)];;
val f : 'a -> (('b * 'a as 'c) list as 'b) -> 'c list = <fun>
#
```

But (as I say) it's something I would avoid.

**Edit 2**

Now that I look at it, your first code sample avoids requiring a recursive type because you
specify two different copies of the list. Until you call the function with the same list, these are potentially different types. So the function type is not recursive. When you call with two copies of the same list, you create a new value with a type that's different than the type of the list. It only works because you're using the same name `l` for different values (with different types). It won't work in a real program, where you'd need a single type representing your list.

As another side comment: the beauty of adding values to the beginning of a list is that the old value of the list is still there. It's the tail of the new list. This seems *lot* closer to what you might actually want to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although it's not necessarily what I'm looking for. Maybe I've stated it wrong. I have a list o pairs (let's name it L) and I want to create a new list ("to add" was just a brachylogy) that would look like this: L @ (L, something). You can easily notice that in the enclosed SSCCEs. How to do this?

Comment: This can't work, there's no reasonable type like that. With `-rectypes` it might be possible, but I really don't think you want this type.

Comment: Okay, but it works if the function is manually called from the interpreter (take a look at the bottom of my question). I thought there may be some way to emulate such behaviour programatically. I've added the output from the interpreter, maybe that will make the issue a bit clearer.

Comment: You're defining a series of different values with the same name. The different values named `l` have successively more and more complicated types. To capture the whole set of possible types that the function can accept and return requires a recursive type. What type does the interpreter show for the type of `add_to_end`?

Comment: Well, I won't even try, because I can't. I have the project for one of my labs and we have clear run specifications, we can't add new arguments. Nevertheless, I wouldn't have tried anyway, I think. Thank you for the answer though, now I know a bit more about the language.

Comment: `val add_to_end : ('a * 'b) list -> 'a -> 'b -> ('a * 'b) list = <fun>` that's what is shows.

Comment: That's not what it shows for me. I had to use `-rectypes`, and it shows the following type: `val add_to_end : (('a * 'c as 'b) list as 'a) -> 'c -> 'b list = <fun>`

Comment: Maybe it's the OCaml version. Mine is 3.12.1. We're both talking about my first code snippet, right?

Comment: Yes, first code snippet. I'll transcribe my session above. You might try starting with fresh session (too many comments here according to SO).